# nth-child() issues in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

hello friends folowing is my code

HTML

```
<div class="quick_link">
    <ul>
        <li>iPad App Edition</li>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Digital Edition</li>
        <li>Press Room</li>
        <li>Privacy & Terms of Use</li>
        <li>Site Map</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>Community Guidelines</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.quick_link li:nth-child(even)').css('color','red');
})​
```

using this code i can change the colour of every even child u can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Nbhp/2/). But problem is i want to change the colour of every fourth child but i dont know how to do that

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

use the `n` variable for this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Nbhp/3/

```
.quick_link li:nth-child(4n)
```

you can find the docs here http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

as Jensgram points out you can find a detailed explanation about the nth-child selector at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: oh thanks a lot .. its working fine ... will you plz explain what is the use oh 'n' in your code and where is this define .. sorry m asking more ...

Comment: @Kamal See [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo). Support listed at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child).

Comment: @jensgram, support doesn't really apply here though since jquery uses its own engine for browser unsupported selectors

Comment: @red-X True that. I didn't really reflect on the jQuery part :)

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
:nth-child(3n+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.quick_link>ul>li:nth-child(even)').css('color','red');
```